# Material UI - Slider: Display only the lowest and the highest markLabel

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to Material Ui and cannot figure out, how to only display the lowest and the highest markLabel in an Material UI slider component..

[range slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAj49.png)

In this example I would like to display "1888" and "2019" only.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `marks` prop can be passed an array, for example:

```
marks={[{ value: 1888 }, { value: 2019 }]}
```

> Marks indicate predetermined values to which the user can move the
> slider. If true the marks will be spaced according the value of the
> step prop. If an array, it should contain objects with value and an
> optional label keys.

https://material-ui.com/api/slider/#props

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I see my mistake now. I was  generating the marks dynamically by iterating over an array. My mistake was to provide a value and a label for each mark. Now I changed my code, so that only the first and the last entry of my array array are labeld.